# WinCE : What does mean the error: U1073: don't know how to make

Tags: compiler-errors, build-process, windows-ce

After trying to build a WinCE OS image for ARM V4 I encountered the following error

**NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\lmemhs.lib'**

Then I decided to run an Advanced Command "Rebuild Current BSP and Subprojects" and I found next error.

**BUILD: [01:0000002558:ERRORE] NMAKE :  U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINCE600\OSDesigns\PENTA_ARM_PC\PENTA_ARM_PC\Wince600\SMDKC100_ARMV4I\cesysgen\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\gpe.lib'
BUILD: [01:0000002560:ERRORE] NMAKE.EXE TargetLibFiles  -i -c BUILDMSG=Stop.  BUILDROOT=C:\WINCE600\PLATFORM\SMDKC100 CLEANBUILD=1 LINKONLY=1 NOPASS0=1 failed - rc = 2**

What does this mean ?
Why these files are missing? Are they part of the Win CE or the ARM BSP ?
I am using Win CE 6.0 Trial.

Comment: Since GPE stands for [Graphics Primitive Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee481906.aspx) I would say that your BSP has a problem and is not building properly. Did you do a sysgen before building your BSP?

Comment: Yes I did with the same problem. I suppose the problem is in the lmemhs.lib file. I am not sure but, when I installed the WinCE development environment the installer asked me if I want to work with ARM or x86. My previous project was intended for x86 so I installed x86. My current project is for ARM. I suppose that lmemhs.lib is something related to memory management that should be different on ARM. Maybe I am wrong but it looks like that is the problem. I do not understand why MS took this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GPE stands for [Graphics Primitive Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee481906.aspx) I would say that your BSP is encountering a problem and is not building properly.

You mentioned in comments that you did not install ARM support on your development environment, and you also said that your target system is an ARM device. It turns out that you **cannot** build an ARM platform if you do not install ARM support on your development environment.

It seems you will have to re-install (or install in another system) your development environment with ARM support, and apply a sysgen operation on your solution.

Comment: I would like to know how to install the support for both ARM and x86. At one step in the installation the installer asked me to select x86 or ARM (both was impossible), so how to have both in do not know. Anyway after installing x86 I was able to select some ARM template. Why is this possible, I do not know.

Comment: My bad... I double-checked on a system with WinCE installed, I tried to build a dummy OS image with an X86 BSP (I usually target ARM devices) and I got the same error you got.

Comment: So what do you think, can we say that this is the possible cause of my problem ? The Win CE installation targeting one of possible platforms.

Comment: @Patrik That seems to be the case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

it's probably due the fact that you installed the x86 rollup update (only) but not the arm4i rollup. this file is updated/added by wince r3 rollup

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36505

choose the arm4i download